# Unable to access website remotely

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, iis-6, internet-explorer-10

My website is hosted on iis 6.0.I trying to access from other machine via host machine ip it show only login page after shows "page cannot be displayed" error for following scenario.

In internet explorer,in 1st i open youtube, in 2nd tab i open gmail, in third tab i open my website remotely then login page working properly but other pages are not displayed.

This scenario is not occur in Other browsers, but my client requirement is strictly use IE

I also tried, added that website in trusted site,also turn off firewall but no success.

Also This problem occur only in IE8,IE9 or other updated version.

Comment: "Page cannot be displayed" is not a useful error from IE, it says that for a lot of things. Have you tried the IE developer tools to see what it does in the HTTP request / response? Have you any logs from IIS or ASP.Net to say what happens? You could install Fiddler to intercept the traffic and see what's happening. (I also don't follow the significance of YouTube or GMail in this, or what you mean by "open my website remotely"). Can you edit your question with some more details, please?

Comment: Interface log as follows

Comment: at System.Threading.Thread.AbortInternal()
   at System.Threading.Thread.Abort(Object stateInfo)
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.AbortCurrentThread()
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.End()
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.Redirect(String url, Boolean endResponse, Boolean permanent)

Comment: I used website in intranet on other machine using like this

Comment: http:\\ip\website name.aspx